# Returning variable from .then function

Tags: javascript

I would like to get a varible from inside .then function. I cannot return the variable called d.isOnline to where it is called.Can you help me ? Thanks.

```
function find_online(id){
            Store.Presence.find(id).then(function(d){
                if (d.isOnline)
                    return d.isOnline;
                else
                    return d.isOnline;
            });
        }

var id = '1234';
var isOnline = find_online(id);  //I CANNOT GET IT HERE
```

Comment: Please see [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992), which this duplicates.

Comment: In this case all you need to do is `return` the value of `Store.presence.find()` and then put the code that needs the return value in another `then()` callback.

Comment: Might as well return a Promise and fetch data in a `then()` callback.